# Writing loop statement for active workbook

Tags: vba, loops, excel

First of all, don't laugh. And if you do, just do it quietly. I have no idea how to write looping Visual basic, but I took my best shot. I'm trying to learn VBA as best I can, by doing, and I just need a push in the right direction. The idea is I want to write a simple macro that looks at each worksheet, evaluates whether or not there is grouping in rows 19-43,if there is grouping, gets rid of the grouping, if there is not grouping, go to the next worksheet, and if there is no more worksheets, end the loop.

Here's my attempt which obviously did not work.

Dim V As Variant

```
V = ActiveWorksheet

For Each V In Workbook

Rows("a29:43").Select

Selection.Rows.Ungroup

Next
```

Now, I also have no idea what the qualification is to say something like if it is grouped, then this, if not grouped, then this. I would imagine it's something like grouping = true but I couldn't figure it out. I am VERY grateful to any who spare some time to look at this.

Comment: `For Each V In Sheets`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the collection that you want to iterate over, so in this case it would be the worksheets contained in the workbook:

```
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sht As WorkSheet

Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook

For Each sht In wbk.Worksheets

  sht.Rows("a29:43").Select ' this may give you trouble. Possibly try sht.Range("a29:a43").Select?

  Selection.Rows.Ungroup

Next

Set wbk = Nothing ' Clean up our objects. Just to be sure.
```

As an aside, I don't know if it needs mentioned but just in case, I'd recommend you avoid ever using single-character variable names.

Comment: First off, thanks for taking time to write a solution. When I run this solution it says "Run time error 424" object required. It points to the line "For each V in workbook.worksheets". Do you have any idea why that would be?

Comment: Also, thank you for poiting out the downside of using single-character names. Do you have any advice for growing into a VBA pro like you? Remember, I'm starting from pretty much scratch.

Comment: LOL at "Pro". I think a healthy dose of self-loathing and indifference towards decent object-oriented programming techniques is a good start. After that, I'd suggest using Excel's "Record Macro" option to see some of the language or steps taken to achieve simple tasks. These are often very verbose but allow you to see the commands being used to achieve a result. Following that, just a lot of fiddling to practice stuff and test things out for yourself. It's a fairly intuitive language to pick up.

Comment: ungroup method of range class failed error on the last line "selection.rows.ungroup" thoughts?

Comment: I suspect if you're working with grouped rows you can't define a specific area as you've defined here. You'll need to select the entire row: `sht.Rows("29:43")`. Also, if you get an error calling the "Ungroup" method, chances are that selected range wasn't grouped to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. As per @pnuts, you're missing an 'A' in your target range. This can be critical.
2. `Ungroup` will fail if rows are not grouped. This works kind of like `Autofilter`.
3. Best practices would be to use `Range`--not `Rows`, and just use the `Rows` property of `Range`--when dealing with target cells, unless a different approach is necessary or justified.

Here's a not-so-different take. Note the clear and explicit declarations of each variable. Also, read the comments. They're not the best, but they can help you on your apparent quest to learn more VBA. ;)

```
Sub UngroupRanges()

    Dim wBk As Workbook, wSht As Worksheet
    Dim rTarget As Range

    Set wBk = ThisWorkbook 'Let wBk be this workbook.

    For Each wSht In wBk.Worksheets 'Read: for each sheet in this workbook's collection of worksheets.
        Set rTarget = wSht.Range("A29:A43") 'Read: I'll be setting rTarget as my target cells.
        On Error Resume Next 'Read: If I hit an error after this line, I'll just continue executing.
        rTarget.Rows.Ungroup 'Read: For all rows in rTarget, I'll do an ungroup.
        On Error GoTo 0 'Read: If I hit an error after this, I won't skip anymore.
    Next wSht 'Read: Move on to next worksheet.

    Set wBk = Nothing 'Read: Release the assignment of this workbook to wBk.

End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Really good stuff here. Thanks for sharing. You've taught me some good stuff with this one. Unfortunately, when I add this into my VBA, and execute it, nothing happens. When I hit alt + F11 and view the code, the name is highlighted in yellow, which I'm not sure why. I literally pasted exactly what you wrote into the window. But even if it doesn't work, this is some interesting stuff. Thanks for taking a swing at this.

Comment: Which part exactly turns yellow and what error message is shown? This part: `Sub UngroupRange()`? If so, change the name to something else like `Sub Boom()` or whatever. It basically means that you have another macro with the same name. Also, make sure it's inside a module and not a sheet.